# ASP.NET MVC app application/json response content mysteriously being overwritten by text/html content

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have built out the functionality of an oauth2 server in an ASP.NET MVC app.

It is all working correctly and to spec for all the non-error producing positive cases.  But I am running into a problem where it seems MVC is wanting to inject text/html where I have specified application/json very late in the mix.

And this is doubly strange because if I test using a tool like soap UI to post to my endpoint, and the soap UI is running on the same machine as my server is running, the error results come back perfectly and as specified.  But if I test using soap UI on a different machine, even on my network, then the JSON I am trying to write is being overwritten with some injected text/html.

First the code snippet, which I have simplified for this question.  The controller action that is returning the JsonResult looks like this:

```
    public JsonResult RefreshOauth2Token(string grant_type, string client_id, string client_secret, string refresh_token)
    {
        try
        {
            var resultFromMyDB = DoMyBusinessToRefreshToken(string grant_type, string client_id, string client_secret, string refresh_token);

            // This positive case works perfectly.
            return Json(new
            {
                access_token = resultFromMyDB.AccessToken,
                token_type = resultFromMyDB.TokenType,
                expires_in = resultFromMyDB.ExpiresInSeconds,
                refresh_token = resultFromMyDB.RefreshToken
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error;
            string errorDescription = e.Message;

            switch (e)
            {
                case MyInvalidClientException:
                    error = "invalid_client";
                    Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    break;
                case MyInvalidGrantException:
                    error = "invalid_grant";
                    Response.StatusCode = 400;
                    break;
                case MyInvalidRequestException:
                    error = "invalid_request";
                    Response.StatusCode = 400;
                    break;
                case MyUnsupportedGrantTypeException:
                    error = "unsupported_grant_type";
                    Response.StatusCode = 400;
                    break;
                case MyUnsupportedTokenTypeException:
                    error = "unsupported_token_type";
                    Response.StatusCode = 400;
                    break;
                default:
                    error = "server_error";
                    Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    break;
            }
            Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

            // When I trace code to this point, everything looks fine.
            // But for some reason something subverts my JSON much farther down the pipeline....
            return Json(new { error, error_description = errorDescription });
        }
    }
```

Here is what the posted request looks like in my trial:

```
POST https://localhost/oauth2token HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 245
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=ObsfucatedForStackOverflow&client_secret=ObsfucatedForStackOverflow&refresh_token=ObsfucatedForStackOverflow
```

And here is the correct result, appropriately indicating an error, and rendered as JSON:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Date: Thu, 25 Mar 2021 22:24:06 GMT
Content-Length: 71

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid Oauth2 Client."}
```

But if I now move to a different machine to run soapUI, to post the request, this time posted as:

```
POST https://my.machine.com/oauth2token HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 245
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=ObsfucatedForStackOverflow&client_secret=ObsfucatedForStackOverflow&refresh_token=ObsfucatedForStackOverflow
```

The response keeps the status code of 401 (correctly) but somehow the application/json content type has been overwritten with text/html, and the actual content has also been overwritten:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: -1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Date: Thu, 25 Mar 2021 22:29:46 GMT
Content-Length: 1293

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not the desired behavior, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what is injecting the html code.  Is it possible that it isn't even MVC but IIS?  How can force this behavior that is trying to "help" me by injecting stuff I don't want to stop injecting?  I just want to leave the JSON alone.

Please note that the injected HTML is not from forms authentication.  If you look at the c# source code above, you will see that forms authentication is being suppressed.  (Without that line of code, a whole different HTML page is injected).

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Microsoft has provided another flag that will suppress this behavior.

In addition to:

```
Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

Turns out you ALSO need to set:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

in order to get IIS to stay out of your business.